# Fetch different data from the same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have a table named users. I have stored users and the franchise in the same table. and while storing users I have stored franchise id as well in that same table with the row. so how can I fetch franchise information along with the user information...???

```
 return  $data= DB::table('users')
            ->join('tbl_customergroups', 'tbl_customergroups.customergroup_id', 'users.group_id')
            ->where('users.user_type', 2)
            ->where('users.id', 'users.franchise_id')
            ->where('users.status', 0)
            ->orWhere('users.user_type', 5)
            ->select('tbl_customergroups.*', 'users.*')
            ->latest('users.created_at')
            ->paginate(10);
```

**User's table  schema :**

````
            $table->string('franchise_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('date_of_join')->nullable();
            $table->string('franchise_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique(); ```
````

Comment: In the query you are using `user.group_id` & `user.status` but the schema doesn't have those columns. It is also unclear what data are you trying to fetch. If there is no `franchise` table, then what other Franchise data you want to get? The query indicates you are trying to fetch data from `tbl_customergroups` for the user's group. Please try to state clearly what data are you trying to fetch from which all tables.

Comment: question so franchise_id point to an other row of the user table ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#:%7E:text=supported%20by%20Eloquent.-,One%20To%20One,-A%20one%2Dto) solutions, and I am assuming that there is a relation between the users model and the franchise model, this could be a possible solution:

Your User model should have a function like this:

```
public function franchise(){
   return $this->hasOne(Franchise::class);
}
```

In your controller you have to fetch the franchise using a user model like this:

```
User::with('franchise')->get();
```

Comment: Sir, Please re-read the question again. there is no franchise table. There is only one table that is USERS. I have stored both users and franchises in the same table.

Comment: Can you share your users table schema?

Comment: I have updated the schema sir.

Comment: When you have the franchise ID in your users table then what exactly do you want, when you say 'how can I fetch franchise information'?